# XML Schema same attributes names but different specific attribute sets of values?

Tags: xsd, attributes

I wish to create a repeating same named element with two attributes for which the values of each are tied to each other. i.e.

```
<anElement id="R1" description="Some definition for R1"/>  
<anElement id="R2" description="Some definition for R2"/>
```

Ideally I would define "groups" of id and description attributes together and reference one of the groups for each instance of anElement element.

```
<complexType name="RElements">
    <choice>
        <element name="anElement" type="R1Group"/>
        <element name="anElement" type="R2Group"/>
    </choice>
</complexType>
<complexType name="RElementsType">
    <sequence>
        <element ref="RElements" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

But Choice doesn't allow multiples of the same element name.  I see discussions about how to have multiple elements of the same name but none allow additional attributes let alone having attributes tied to each other.  The only way that I can get close is by having a different named element based on the id.  i.e.

```
<R1 id="R1" description="Some definition for R1"/>  
<R2 id="R2" description="Some definition for R2"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information.

Basically to achieve the XML you have provided a simple schema like this would suffice.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2015 Developer Bundle Edition 13.0.3.5737 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="RootElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="anElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name="descritpion" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However you mention that the attribute values id and description are linked, you may be able to constrain these, but you need to provide more info. Also I'm not sure why you are looking at choices? Its difficult to see what your attempting give you only provide snippets of the schema

---

To include the constraints described in later comments the following schema would allow this, but force a change in the XML structure

```
<AnElement id="E1"> Exterminator serial <ref id="E1"/> </AnElement>
```

[image: XSD drawn using Liquid XML Studio]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2015 Developer Bundle Edition 13.0.0.5686 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="RootElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="AnElement">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ref" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:key name="IDVal">
                        <xs:selector xpath="." />
                        <xs:field xpath="@id" />
                    </xs:key>
                    <xs:keyref name="IdRef" refer="IDVal">
                        <xs:selector xpath="ref" />
                        <xs:field xpath="@id" />
                    </xs:keyref>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I wish to relate an id with a description.   So for each of the one or more occurrence of element named anElement is an id with exactly one description for it.  So the choice is for one of the combination of id and description attributes that are tied together.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not really getting it, can you provide a sample of the XML you are trying to produce.

Comment: <AnElement id="E1" description="Exterminator serial #1"/>  <AnElement id="E2" description="Exterminator serial #2"/>  but the following must never be allowed:  <AnElement id="E1" description="Exterminator serial #2"/>  <AnElement id="E2" description="Exterminator serial #1"/>

Comment: You can't constrain a reference within a block of text like that. If you reformed the XML to look like this, you could probably use Key Ref's to define a rule <AnElement id="E1"> Exterminator serial <ref id="E1"/> </AnElement>, see amended answer